# UITableViewCell/UITableView: Dynamic resizing of 2 UILabels in UITableViewCell is flickering

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

[image: UITableViewCell with two Dynamic UILabels]

I want to display some thing like this in the image where two UILabels vertically next to another expanding based on the text.

This is how I tried doing it.

For the label1 one I am using NSMutableAttributedString so that I can set line spacing. Label2 is with normal String text.

Properties of UITableView

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 110
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

heightForRowAtIndexPath() is not implemented as these properties will take care of the height dynamically

In CellForRowAtIndexPath()

```
var paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 15
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "HUGE TEXT 1")
attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,     value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
myCell.label1.attributedText = attrString
myCell.label2.text = "HUGE TEXT 2"
```

Problem: When scrolling down (New cells coming from downwards) have no problem, but when I scroll upwards(New cells coming from upwards) the cells start flickering and then resizing to fit at the end of the scroll. The flicker is only on the UILabel2. I don't seem to find any solution in stack overflow for this kind of layout.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, in your UITableViewCell implement this method :

```
+ (CGFloat) cellHeightForContent:(NSString)aContent {
    CGFloat result = 0;
    CGSize textDims = [aContent getCorrectSizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(kLabelWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    result = 2 * kMarginHeight + textDims.height;

    return result;
}
```

The value returned by this method will be used in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

After that, you need to define the method `getCorrectSizeWithFont` in an NSString Category, like that :

```
- (CGSize)getCorrectSizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    NSMutableDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    [attrsDictionary setObject:paragraphStyle forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];

    NSMutableAttributedString* attrStrWithLinks = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self attributes:attrsDictionary];
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attrStrWithLinks);
    CGSize sz = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter,CFRangeMake(0,0),NULL,CGSizeMake(size.width,CGFLOAT_MAX),NULL);
    if (framesetter) CFRelease(framesetter);
    return CGSizeMake(sz.width,sz.height);
}
```